# Non-linear regression using custom neural network in MatLab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, non-linear-regression

I am very new to MatLab. I got a task for modelling non-linear regression using neural network in MatLab.

I need to create a two-layer neural network where:

1. The first layer is N neurons with sigmoid activation function.
2. The second layer is layer with one neuron and a linear activation
   function.

Here is how I implemented the network:

```
net = network(N, 2);
net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'logsig';
net.layers{1}.size = N
net.layers{2}.size = 1;
```

Is this implementation correct? How should I assign the linear activation function to the second layer?

Answer (score 0):

A quick reading of the Matlab help on the `nntransfer` function gives you the list of all possible transfer functions you can use. In your case I think you should either try the `poslin` (positive linear) or the `purelin` one (pure linear).

When you have such questions, the best way is actually to 'ask' Matlab the possibilities you have.
In this case, I just typed `net.layers{2}` in the Matlab console window. This displays the list of the parameters of the 2nd layer. Then, you just click on the link `TransferFcn` and the Matlab help with the possible options for this parameter value automatically opens. This works for any parameter of your neural network ;)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't determine the transfer function for the second layer.

```
net.layers{2}.transferFcn='pureline'
```

The rest is OK.